# Data structure to find the nearest untaken element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array A[0..N-1] containing N elements  and a list containing M indexes. Each index in the list corresponds to an element in the array. For example, an index of 0 corresponds to A[0], an index of 1 corresponds to A[1]

I want to process the list sequentially from the first index to the last index as follows:
For the current index i,

1. if A[i] is not taken, then A[i] will be taken.
2. if A[i] is taken, then the smallest j > i where A[j] is not taken will be chosen and A[j] will be taken. If there is no such element, output -1

I want to output an array B of length M where B[i] denotes the index of element taken. I wonder how do I do it in linear complexity. (i.e. O(N) or O(M)). What data structure could be used?

Comment: I don't think there's a linear complexity solution. Also, your step 2 is misworded and step 3 (if A[i] is taken and there is no j > i where A[j] is not taken) is not defined.

Comment: @Ouroborus if there is no j > i where A[j] is not taken then just output -1

Comment: @Ouroborus How about a non-quadratic solution?

Comment: I think you can get at least `O(M log(M))` since this can be done via sorting.

Comment: @Ouroborus How do you do it via sorting? The order of the list matters

Comment: Create another list, M', where each element contains a reference to an element in M, e.g. M'[i] refers to M[i]. Sort M' using a sorting algorithm that keeps order for same values and compares the referenced values. Iterate over M', to increment values as needed, such that M'[i] > M'[i-1].

Comment: No, I guess that wouldn't work. If you had `[4,5,4]` you get `[4,6,5]` but should get `[4,5,6]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for an O(M*logM) algorithm.

At the start, insert all M i-indexes of the list into a sorted tree allowing doubles. The steps become,

1. If A[i] is not taken, then take A[i]. Remove the i from the tree.
2. If A[i] is taken, then the smallest j > i where A[j] is not taken will be chosen and A[j] will be taken. The smallest j>i is readily available after i in the tree. If there is no such j, output -1. Otherwise, remove the j from the tree.